# Check to see if the application has closed

Tags: c#, forms, xna

I have a C# windows form, it has a XNA Graphicsdevice withing the pictureBox. The problem I am having is that when I press the close button, it closes the Form, but the graphicsDevice is still running. I am trying to set up a way where if the close button has been pressed and if it has, it closes the entire application.

I created a method that checks the closes reason and if it's based on the user close it would shut down the application. The problem is, is that I don't know how to call upon this method in the windowsform.cs class.

```
 void ClosingEvent(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you open or start this XNA Graphicsdevice? Is it running in separate process?

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't see exactly how it would be implemented upon closing the application.